# How to Post data on IBM connections from a local file

Tags: ibm-connections

I use `IBM connections 5.5` and i want to post data on connections, from a local file(.docs or .txt), is there a default components on IBM connectionsthat enables this? Or should i develop an application that do this job from the scratch? Is there any API that can help me to achieve that?

Comment: I think you will have to develop an application from scratch for that purpose. You can use IBM connections REST apis to post data on connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to post (and where), the APIs vary, of course:

1) If you want to post information to users, look into the [ActivityStreams API](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%205.5%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=IBM_Connections_Activity_Stream_API_ic55&content=apicontent)

2) If you want to post/file the documents themselves, look into the [Files API](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%205.5%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Working_with_files_ic55&content=apicontent)

Cheers,
Markus